# When warnings occur in a loop in R, is it possible to report and extract which iteration it occurs in?

Tags: r

I currently have some code where I am looping over a regression model and for some iterations, there appears a warning message. For example:

```
for(i in 1:100){
    set.seed(i)  
    x  = c(runif(100, min=-3, max=3), 200)
    y  = rbinom(101, size=1, prob=1/(1+e^(-x))
    m  = glm(y~x, family=binomial)
}
```

There will be warnings coming out of `glm(y~x, family=binomial)` but it is only reported at the end with:

```
 There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Is there a way to see which iteration caused which warnings and be able to report results in the end for those that caused warnings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `tryCatch`

```
for(i in 1:100){ 
  set.seed(i)                        
  x  = c(runif(100, min=-3, max=3), 200) 
  y  = rbinom(101, size=1, prob=1/(1+exp(-x)))
  tryCatch({m   <-  glm(y~x, family=binomial)}, warning=function(w) print(i))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

See `tryCatch`, argument `finally`.

```
for(i in 1:100){ 
 set.seed(i)                        
 x  <- c(runif(100, min=-3, max=3), 200) 
 y  <- rbinom(101, size=1, prob=1/(1+exp(-x)))
 m  <- tryCatch(glm(y~x, family = binomial), finally = print(i))
}
```

Also, I've changed the equal sign to the assignment arrow `<-`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i in 1:100){ 
  set.seed(i)                        
  x  = c(runif(100, min=-3, max=3), 200) 
  y  = rbinom(101, size=1, prob=1/(1+exp(-x)))
  tryCatch({glm(y~x, family=binomial)}, warning=function(w) print(i))
}
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: This is functionally equivalent to platypus' answer, except that you no longer store the model in m